# Autosum and other calculations in word table - Mac

Tags: macos, ms-word

I have the following working on Word 2007 on PC:

`"=SUM(ABOVE)"` <- this cell has bookmark called "thesum"

In the cell under I have `"=thesum * 0,25"` <- this cell has a bookmark called "mva"

In the cell under again, I have `"=mva+thesum"`

When I try it on Mac running Word 2008 I get a syntax error in the fields doing calculations with the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Bookmarks works just great, the thing was that the Mac running word 2008 had another decimal separator than the PC running word 2007.

My mac used . as decimal seperator when my PC used ,

That's why I got the syntax error if anyone is wondering about this.